# Shopify Disable product from channels (Publication assess)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've been trying to disable products via API from specific channels, other than the "Online Store" but with no luck for now.

Currently, I'm able to disable a product from the "Online Store" sales channel with "published: false", but this property is listed as deprecated and suggested to use the Publication object.

Requesting the Publication object keeps requiring the read_publications,write_publications access, but these scopes are missing as it says "Oauth error missing_shopify_permission: read_publications,write_publications".

Here https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/write-publications-and-read-publications-access/m-... I saw that there is a follow-up which can help in achieving this, but I still got no response from Shopify forums or support regarding it.

My app is a public one and the functionality I need to create is to disable the specific product from all sales channels and then enable it only on the "Online store" channel.

I found an app that manages to do that, so I think there should be a way, but I couldn't find this in the docs. The app's name is "Bulk Product Edit (BPE)"

Any idea how I can get this working?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to control the visibility (publish or unpublish) of a product on a channel other than Point of Sale or Online Store, this is not possible via the API at the moment. You can only disable enable from online store.

Answer (score 0):

"published" is marked as deprecated on [GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/products-and-collections/productupdate?api%5Bversion%5D=2021-01#productinput-fields-2021-01) but not on [Rest Admin API (Search 'Create a new unpublished product')](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product#index-2021-01).

So you can still use the Rest Admin API. It's not reliable though. I tested the `product.published_scope = 'web'` But it's not working occasionally